# RewriteRule not working on htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cdn

I've tried my best over the past few days, but can't crack this. Grateful for any advise.
Currently, our css files are on our server, e.g.
http://www.yellowgiraffe.in/media/css/06427155c7973881a2250449796e95f1.css

Now we want the css to be picked up from the CDN (Akamai)
http://css.yellowgiraffe.in/06427155c7973881a2250449796e95f1.css (on CDN)

Am putting down the relevant lines from htaccess below. The "#" is intentional for the purpose of this post, and not a inadvertent slip

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteLog "/var/log/rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 3
############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
RewriteBase /
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
RewriteRule ^media/css/(.*) http://css.yellowgiraffe.in/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Post making the above changes to htaccess, when I run inspect browser, I still see the old URL. Fyi - To check the regex I used Scriptular

Thanks in advance for any inputs

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but is the rewrite rule you want to use, the last line above?  It looks commented out with a single #.  Maybe try removing that and restarting apache to make sure nothing is cached.

http://eppand.com/how-to-comment-in-a-htaccess-file/

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^media/css/(.*) http://css.yellowgiraffe.in/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes the last line is the RewriteRule that we want to run. We ran it w/o the "#"

Comment: I've even tried restarting apache. But it didn't do the trick

Comment: Any caching on the server or plugins that may have old urls?

Comment: We've tried the suggestions above .. (removing #, caching). For some reason it doesn't seem to be working